# Find 5th degree polynomial equation from points?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, graphing-functions

I have a set of estimated points, listed below, and I would like to know how to calculate the polynomial.

I've looked at Wikipedia, and I don't quite understand how at works. Example 1 on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Example_1 seems to be the closest to what I'm trying to do, but I don't know how to get the basis polynomials, i.e. turning the middle section into the right section. I can probably get it to the interpolating section from there.

My points are as follows:
800, 175; 600, 125; 400, 100; 200, 125; 0,0; -200, -125; -400, -100; -600, -125; -800, -175.

Eventually, I'm going to try and dynamically swap out the points above in the program I'm building, so I could really use a step by step description. I read [Determining Coefficients of a Finite Degree Polynomial $f$ from the Sequence $\{f(k)\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10319/determining-coefficients-of-a-finite-degree-polynomial-f-from-the-sequence-f), but I don't quite follow it. It's very possible I'm out of my depth and should re-think what I'm trying to accomplish, but I'd really like to try this. Thanks!

Comment: The post you linked to assumed the $x$-coordinates are $1,2,3,\dots$, so it isn't general enough for your purposes. If you say the polynomial is $P(x)$ with undetermined coefficients, then the system $P(x_i)=y_i$ for $i=0,1,2,\dots$ is a linear system in those coefficients that can be solved with linear algebra. As for Lagrange polynomials, the Wikipedia has the formulas for the basis polynomials explicitly written - so where is your issue specifically? Define $Q_j(z)$ to be the product of factors $(z-x_i)$ for all $i$ except $i=j$; then $$\ell_j(z)=Q_j(z)/Q_j(x_j)$$ are the basis polynomials.

Comment: Also, how do you figure the interpolated polynomial will be $5$-th degree?

Comment: The Lagrange polynomial passes exactly through the data points.  Absent a lucky coincidence, it generates an $n-1$ degree polynomial from $n$ points, so in your case it would be $8$th degree (except for the antisymmetry, which would reduce it to $7$th degree)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know for a fact that your points lie on a polynomial of degree 5, you can use finite differences. This is especially easy when the $x$-values are in arithmetic progression, as in your case. Write the $y$-values:

175  125  100  125  0  -125  -100  -125  -175

Then write the difference between each number and the next:

-50  -25  25  -125  -125  25  -25  -50

Again:

25  50  -150  0  150  -50  -25

Again:

25  -200  150  150  -200  25

Again:

-225  350  0  -350  225

And once more:

575  -350  -350  575

Now if your points were really from a polynomial of degree 5, that last line would have been constant, but it's not, so they're not. But after all, you said they were estimated points - they still might be *close* to some polynomial of degree 5. To find the polynomial of degree 5 that comes closest to your points, there is a method called *least squares*, and there are many expositions of it on the web.

EDIT: Here's a start on least squares:

You want a polynomial $p(x)=ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f$ such that $p(800)=175$, $p(600)=125$, etc. We already know that's impossible, so we settle for making all the numbers $p(800)-175$, $p(600)-125$, etc., small. In fact, we form the quantity $$(p(800)-175)^2+(p(600)-125)^2+\cdots+(p(-800)-175)^2$$ and we try to minimize it. This quantity is a function of the 6 variables $a,b,c,d,e,f$, and there are standard calculus techniques for minimizing such a function. It gets very messy, but fortunately you don't actually have to do it; someone has done it for you, in the most general case, and found that you can write down a very simple matrix equation which you can solve for the unknowns $a,b,c,d,e,f$. And that's what you'll find if you search for least squares polynomial fit.

Answer (score 2):

With 9 points your data will not fit a 5th degree polynomial exactly.  You need a [least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) fit, which will smooth things.  More information is found in chapter 15 of [Numerical Recipes](http://nr.com/) (obsolete versions are free) or any numerical analysis textbook.  Your particular data is odd $(f(-x)=-f(x)$, so only $x, x^3, x^5$ terms will appear.  I rescaled your x values for the fit below.  You can rescale them back by dividing the coefficients by $200^{\text{power of x}}$.  It doesn't look like a very good fit, but Excel claims it is the best you will get.  The even order terms are roundoff error and should be ignored.

[image]

Comment: The numerical recipes book is definitely a great resource. I'm going to be looking through that more.